# ClassLoader.php:444 или накосячил с Auth

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. При переносе папки Auth в папку Admin выдаёт ошибку

```html
 ErrorException  : include(C:\wamp64\www\jolyAdmin\vendor\composer/../../app/H

  at C:\wamp64\www\jolyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444
    440|  * Prevents access to $this/self from included files.
    441|  */
    442| function includeFile($file)
    443| {
  > 444|     include $file;
    445| }
    446| 

  Exception trace:

  1   include()
      C:\wamp64\www\jolyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444

  2   Composer\Autoload\includeFile("C:\wamp64\www\jolyAdmin\vendor\composer/../
      C:\wamp64\www\jolyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

При её возвращении на прежнее место ошибка не фикситься.
Изначально хотел сделать роуты на типе admin/login, admin/logout привязав это всё к namespace admin.

WEB.PHP

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin', 'prefix'=>'admin'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Ошибка возникает при вызове php artisan route:list

Comment: Нельзя просто взять и перенести одну папку, являющуюся частью структуры PSR проекта Laravel в другую, не поменяв конфигурационные настройки. Зачем вы это сделали, и для чего? Будет лучше вернуть всё на место, сдампить Composer через composer dump-autoload, и попробовать решить иначе.

Comment: " Зачем вы это сделали, и для чего?". Мне нужна авторизация только для админа и для этого я решил сделать всю работу по префиксу admin и для красоты всё в папку Admin. спасибо за ответ. Можно закрывать. Дамп помог